sql server connection failed, despite of right credentials
I'm currently using a MySQL server version 8.3, which I use on my Winform project, I encounter an Issue when I start to run the program and the Database won't connect despite of a right credentials, I also open it in HeidiSQL and told that I enter an incorrect password. It only happens randomly and  when I just turn on my computer,

I usually fix this by opening it in the workbench, and it would just work as always
but before I did, I always chekced the windows Services to see if it's running, and It did.
Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Also please look at the log_error file  (show variables like 'log_error';)
